# Adobe Premiere Pro CC aspect ratio streched

Tags: premiere, aspect

Couple of last times I rendered with Premiere Pro I notified that aspect ratio is stretched by height. I'm rendering 1280x720 at 1.333 aspect, and it worked fine every time till now, I didn't change any settings or anything, video previews are looking normal, and only output is stretched. I'm getting really frustrated here, any help? Here are images of sequence settings and export settings:

[image: sequence settings]

[image: export settings]

Comment: With 1.333 aspect you mean the pixel aspect ratio? In that case it's now wonder your video comes out distorted ... if you want a 1280x720 resolution with a normal video aspect ratio, use quadratic pixels (1.0) instead. I don't fully understand your problem though. Could you provide information about the resolution and pixel aspect ratio of the source material and the desired output format?

Comment: I'm usually using 720p with 1.333 aspect to get that anamorphic look and widescreen, but now when I'm exporting in that way it somehow exports video in 16:9 aspect a stretches it. Footage is from DSLR at 1080p with 16:9 aspect and I'm exporting it in h.264 Match Source preset.

Comment: That still sounds curious to me. Does that mean you deliberately stretch your video? Because a resolution of 1280x720 used with a 1.333 pixel aspect ratio would leave you with a widescreen video that appears stretched in width. If you're using Match Source with your 1080p footage, it will export in 1080p, meaning 16:9 aspect ratio ... if you have set your sequence settings to something other than that, this will lead to all kinds of unwanted results ...

Comment: If a stretched video is really what you want, you should set your sequence settings to match your original videos resolution and pixel aspect ratio and then export it using the video and pixel aspect ratio you want, but I don't see why you should want that ... maybe I just don't understand what you're trying to achieve

Comment: No, I'm not, I'm making sequence at 720p with 1.333 and than scaling footage down to fill, maybe this will reflect it better, here are images of how output should be: http://dupovacemir.ga/wanted-output.jpg and how it actually is: http://dupovacemir.ga/output.jpg

Comment: To be more specific, this is the kind of output I want:  http://dupovacemir.ga/work/demolition-day

Comment: So you're trying to achieve a 2.35:1 video aspect ratio (i.e. widescreen) by scaling the source video to fit and cutting off a strip at either the top or the bottom (or both)? (edit: I just realised you wrote that 10 hourse ago. Now I feel stupid. Sorry) Ok that makes sense (even though I don't really like the idea of cutting parts of your 16:9 image to make it look cooler); so your sequence settings look [like this](http://i.imgur.com/JnnQ7hm.png), is that correct? If so, please post screenshots of your export settings, if the problem only occurs after export, those are most likely the cause

Comment: Yes, thats exactly how it is set, here are the export setting, with and without pixel aspect ratio correction toggled, [with](http://dupovacemir.ga/with.JPG), and [without](http://dupovacemir.ga/without.JPG)

Comment: Ok I've tried to reproduce your problem. After exporting, how did you check the video? Because I got a distorted video when I opened the exported file (exported with 1280x720 at 1.333 PAR) in the VLC media player, which recognised the video as 16:9 rather than 2.35:1. I could correct that by manually switching to this aspect ratio in VLC. I don't know what happens though when uploading that to vimeo (tried that, but now I'm stuck in vimeos converting queue ...)
I'm going to go to bed soon, but I will get back to that tomorrow and see what happens in vimeo!

Comment: Yeah, I'm using Media Player Classic and can also set it manually, but that wont fix anything, but now you see whats the problem, and thanks a lot for the effort.

Comment: Ok I checked the video I uploaded to vimeo, and indeed, it doesn't recognise the 1.333 PAR, resulting in a deformed video. I don't know if the PAR is in some way embedded in the meta data of a video, so I don't ecaxctly have a solution ... however, I came up with a workaround (which is a bit dirty, admittedly); use quadratic pixels instead and adjust the amount of pixels either horizontally to achieve your 2.35:1 aspect ratio; so use either. ~1280x540 or ~1706x720. I know this isn't exactly what you were asking for, but at least it works ... (anamorphic video is a mess either way, so ...)

Comment: ^Posted this as a comment since it isn't really an answer. Sorry I can't help you :( Also, the exact dimension may be slightly wrong, you'll have to try it out or google the correct dimensions, possible widescreeen dimensions should be easy to find

Answer (score 0):

I would check up in the Output window (second image). In the top left there is that option: Scale to Fit. Try changing that. Also check the "Fit" option in the bottom of the window right under the video.

Answer (score 0):

Use square pixels for everything. Avoid pixel dimension stretching at all costs. Unless you're dealing with archive footage or anamorphic lenses, and there's no choice. This advice will make your life easier.